# awk for string comparison with multiple delimiters

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with multiple delimiters, I m looking to compare the value after the first `/` when read from right left with another file.

code :-

```
awk -F'[/|]' NR==FNR{a[$3]; next} ($1 in a )' file1 file2 > output
```

cat file1

```
AAB/BBC/customer|fed|12931|
/customer|fed|982311|
BXC/DEF/OTTA|fed|92374|
AVD/customer|FST|8736481|
FFS/T6TT/BOSTON|money|18922|
GTS/trust/YYYY|opt|62376|
XXY/IJSH/trust|opt|62376|
```

cat file2

```
customer
trust
```

expected output :-

```
AAB/BBC/customer|fed|12931|
/customer|fed|12931|
AVD/customer|FST|8736481|
XXY/IJSH/trust|opt|62376|
```

Comment: Your description `to compare the value after the first / when read from right left` looks incoherent with your expected results. Not my downvote, too.

Comment: I don't understand the point of `NR==FNR`. NR is the total number of input records seen so far, and FNR is the input record number in the current file. Therefore, the expression will be true for **all** records in the first file, and will be false for **all** records in the second file.

Comment: @user1934428 : ur interpretation is exactly correct …. for 1st "pattern" (gosh i hate that word - `"pattern"` - just about the most misleading term one can imagine for what it actually does ) of the code. 2nd file fails all of first action block, but will satisfy second block, while `"next"` bypasses the 2nd block for `file1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F\| '            # just use one FS
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]
    next
}
{
    n=split($1,t,/\//)  # ... and use split to the 1st field
    if(t[n] in a)       # and compare the last split part
        print
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
AAB/BBC/customer|fed|12931|
/customer|fed|982311|
AVD/customer|FST|8736481|
XXY/IJSH/trust|opt|62376|
```

Comment: And how does the lone `a[$1]` work? There is no assignment going on.

Comment: `a[$1]` hashes the first `|` separated word into `a` array with NULL value, as we don't need a value, just the word in the array to match with `if(t[n] in a)`.

Comment: So just the use of  `a[SOMETHING]` in an expression already creates an entry for _SOMETHING_ ! It's a bit like autovivification in Perl. Again something learned!

Comment: Yeah, it's like `a[$1]=""`.

Comment: Now I also understand the purpose of `NR==FNR`....

Answer (score 0):

If you use this `[/|]` you will have 2 delimiters and you will not know what the value after the last pipe was.

Reading your question, you want to compare the first value after the last slash without pipe chars.

If there has to be a `/` present in the string, you can set that as the field separator and check if there are at least 2 fields using `NF > 1`

Then take the last field using `$NF`, split on `|` and check if the first part is present in one of the values of *file2* which are stored in array *a*

```
$cat file1

AAB/BBC/customer|fed|12931|
/customer|fed|982311|
BXC/DEF/OTTA|fed|92374|
AVD/customer|FST|8736481|
FFS/T6TT/BOSTON|money|18922|
GTS/trust/YYYY|opt|62376|
XXY/IJSH/trust|opt|62376|
customer
```

**Example code**

```
awk -F/ '
NR==FNR {a[$1];next}
NF > 1 {
  split($NF, t, "|")
  if(t[1] in a) print
}
' file2 file1
```

**Output**

```
AAB/BBC/customer|fed|12931|
/customer|fed|982311|
AVD/customer|FST|8736481|
XXY/IJSH/trust|opt|62376|
```